# Frank Hertz Experiment vs Photoelectric Effect saturation current

Tags: experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect

I have a doubt. I understand that in the photoelectric effect even a increasing voltage does not imply a increase in current since the rate of emission is determine by the light. However in Frank Hertz Experiment the emission is due to thermoemission and I suppose the temperature constant so the emission is also fixed. On the other hand I've read that in the Frank Hertz experiment the minima follow the Child-Langmuir Law. Leaving aside this last experiment, the ChildLangmuir Law describe the current reaching the anode in vacuum (no collisions). But even if the cathode emission is constant, the current reaching the anode depends on voltage acoording to this law. This contradicts the first about the photoelectric experiment.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are confusing the function of voltage in the photoelectric effect. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html . "Electrons ejected from a sodium metal surface were measured as an electric current. Finding the opposing voltage it took to stop all the electrons gave a measure of the maximum kinetic energy of the electrons in electron volts. "   the plot is versus *maximum* kinetic energy and frequency of light.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is about when the voltage was supporting motion of electrons. That's when saturated current appears.